# How to implement text counter on button click inside each recycler view item

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to implement text counter where an integer will be incremented and decremented inside each recycler view item say 0 to 100 to start with i've tried taking a integer and on button click i did i++ but here the problem is that integer is only limited to a specific position of recyclerview item when i click on button it actually increments the integer but at the same time when i click on button of another item the text counter starts from the already set integer.

This is my recycler view class:

```
public class Mainadapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Mainadapter.exViewHolder> {

    List<OrderItemFragment.Ex> exList;
    Context mContext;
    AlertDialog levelDialog;
    int i=0;
    boolean a = false;
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    Mainadapter(List exList, Context context) {
        this.exList= exList;
        this.mContext = context;

    }
    public static class exViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView exname;
        ImageView exlogo,attach;
        TextView tv;
        ImageView add,sub;



        exViewHolder(View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            exname= itemView.findViewById(R.id.menuname);
            exlogo=itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgmenu);
            attach=itemView.findViewById(R.id.attach);
            tv=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvqty);
            add=itemView.findViewById(R.id.additem);
            sub=itemView.findViewById(R.id.removeitem);



        }


    }
    @Override
    public Mainadapter.exViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
        View viewthigh= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.menu_item,parent,false);
        Mainadapter.exViewHolder evh=new Mainadapter.exViewHolder(viewthigh);
        return evh;


    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final Mainadapter.exViewHolder holder, final int position){
        holder.exname.setText(exList.get(position).name);
        holder.exlogo.setImageResource(exList.get(position).logoId);
        holder.attach.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext,"Attach Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        holder.add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (i!=0&&a==false){
                    i=0;
                    a=false;
                }
                else {
                    holder.tv.setText(String.valueOf(i++));
                }

            }
        });
        holder.sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                holder.tv.setText(String.valueOf(i--));
            }
        });

    }
    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView){
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return  exList.size();
    }
```

Just just can't figure out the logic to reset the integer on click any suggestion will be appreciated.

[image: Screenshot of image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achieve by add one more int variable in your list model class named as "OrderItemFragment.Ex".

Now, you have separate counter for each items in recyclerview.

Suppose you have "count" variable in "OrderItemFragment.Ex".
so, you can perform operation like below:

```html
holder.add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    int i = exList.get(position).count;
                    holder.tv.setText(String.valueOf(i++));
                    exList.get(position).count = i;
            }
        });
holder.sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int i = exList.get(position).count;
                holder.tv.setText(String.valueOf(i--));                         exList.get(position).count = i;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep an array of integers instead of just a variable i, with the size of your list of items:

```
int [] i = new Int [exList.size()];
```

And each time you want to increase instead of `i++`, use `i[position] ++`

Comment: Doesn't work when i click on button nothing happens and also app i crashing with error stating that attemp to invoke interface method int ava.util.list.size() on a null object reference

Comment: You have to invoke the part i = new Int [exList.size()];  when the list exList is not null. When you have data there. Inside this method in your case: Mainadapter(List exList, Context context) {
        this.exList= exList;
        this.mContext = context;

    }